# Documentation of nestjs graphql missing on official docs

Tags: graphql, nestjs

### Documentation of `nestjs` `graphql` missing

The documentation page on `nestjs` site for `nestjs` `graphql` is not reachable the link under `RECIPES` at https://docs.nestjs.com/ is not active ,could be acesssed before at  [https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start
[image: capture]](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start)
 was it removed purposely or how can I get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some issues with a service worker (cache). Let's just open a page in a new incognito window. :)

Comment: thanks a lot , was able to access the page in incognito window, and lots of thanks to for this really awesome framework , the best